# How to position SVG elements when path drawing (React Native)

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, svg

`svg` is very confusing and I really need help configuring this. I think my problems are related to the `ViewBox`, how I'm using `width`, `height`, and `translate`. Essentially my webpage currently looks like this:
[image: Actual]

Essentially, I want to be able to position it so two words are correctly centered underneath where that Profile picture will be. So something like this:
[image: Expected]

Forgive my handwriting, I'm drawing on paint with a mouse. But you get the idea, I want it to be on the same level, centered perfectly beneath the circle. However, I'm new to `svg` and do not entirely understand how I am supposed to position anything at the moment. The animation is not the problem, I have that on lockdown, it's simply putting it where I want to put it. This is my code for the component:

```js
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Text, Animated, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

import { motion, AnimationProps } from "framer-motion";

const pathColor = "black";

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;

const vb = `0 0 ${windowWidth} ${windowHeight}`

const path = {
    transition: {
    duration: 4, //Change this to either slow or hasten the animation
    ease: "easeInOut",
},
variants: {
    visible: {
        pathLength: 1, //Change this to determine how much of the path is drawn when first rendered
},
hidden: {
    pathLength: 0,
    },
},
};

//letters are 2 boxes wide, 3 boxes tall (ignore this)
function Name() {
    return(
        <View>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox={vb}>
                <g transform="translate(400 -500)">
                    <motion.path
                        {...path}
                        animate="visible"
                        initial="hidden"                    
                        d="M 250 250 L 300 100 L 350 250 L 335 200 L 265 200 "
                        fill="none"
                        stroke={pathColor}
                        strokeWidth="6"
                    />
                </g>
            </svg>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Name;
```

I plan on having each letter correspond to a `<svg>`, but adding more letters just messes things up. Also, the content that is supposed to below the Name is pushed way further down. I have an image that is supposed to be at the bottom of the page but that is pushed most likely due to how I'm positioning the `svg` component (a bunch of whitespace is added between the name and image).

Thank you.

Comment: What is the reason for having each letter in its own `<svg>`?

Comment: You’re correct actually. I only need each letter to be it’s own motion.path however that still leaves the translate to be changed. However I don’t know how to position each right next to each other. I have tried changing the x value of the translate but it’s never perfect and the position is always slightly off